# How to suppress section in crystal report based on a condition in formula field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

I have a formula for the conversion of the catcher type in the crystal report:

```
select {command.catcher_type}
case 1:'Bag Net'
case 2:'Beach/Drag Seine'
case 3:'Danish Seine'
case 4:'Gill Net'
case 5:'Handline'
case 6:'Longline'
case 7:'Paaling/Drive-in Net'
case 8:'Push Net'
case 9:'Ring Net'
case 10:'Round Haul Seine'
case 11:'Sardine/Mackerel/Scad Purse Siene'
case 12:'Trawl'
case 13:'Tuna Purse Seine'
case 14:{command.other_gear}
default: 'N/A'
```

this works in my report..

I have to suppress the `section3` of my report depending on the value from the result of the formula above..

here is my formula for the suppression:

```
if('@gear_translate')="13" then
    True
else
    false
```

it doesn't work .. it did not suppressed the section3.

Comment: what is this formula `@gear_translate` and what will be the output of this formula

Comment: formula @gear_translate is the conversion formula i have typed above .. this formula will convert the value of the different catcher type.. the values on the right side will be the output on the crystal report ..

Comment: i have to suppress the section depending on the result of the conversion ..

Answer (score 1):

Result of the formula is a text filed and hence your target formula should be:

```
if {@gear_translate}="Tuna Purse Seine" then
    True
else
    false
```

Comment: is it possible to have multiple section(details) inserted in the crystal reports?

Comment: yes you can have multiple sections.... go to details.. `right click --> Insert section below`